How do I prevent duplication of view results in case a view has relationship with a taxonomy vocabulary?
In version 10.3 multilingual web application my view has a relationship with the core category taxonomy vocabulary.
Filter criteria contains:

published
Two different terms of that vocabulary by is one of with the values A, B.

Sort criteria contains:

Content publishing date (not Taxonomy term publishing date).

I didn't use any translation filter criteria.
From looking at the SQL query there seems to be a JOIN of two tables that I didn't intend to make:
SELECT "node_field_data"."langcode" AS "node_field_data_langcode", "node_field_data"."created" AS "node_field_data_created", "node_field_data"."nid" AS "nid", "taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_qtgwryh"."tid" AS "taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_qtgwryh_tid"
FROM
{node_field_data} "node_field_data"
LEFT JOIN {node__field_qtgwryh} "node__field_qtgwryh" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_qtgwryh.entity_id AND node__field_qtgwryh.deleted = '0' AND (node__field_qtgwryh.langcode = node_field_data.langcode OR node__field_qtgwryh.bundle IN ( 'dp_qydwm_wrgny', 'dp_mwrh_prty', 'dp_drwpl', 'dp_mdyh_hbrtyt', 'dp_syrwty_twkn', 'dp_hswn_trym_w_lynwqs', 'dp_drwm_mzrh_syh', 'dp_mdynh', 'dp_mzrh_syh', 'dp_ntwrwptyh', 'dp_mshr_lqtrwny', 'dp_gybwy_tr', 'dp_byqvrt_rgvnym', 'dp_tyt', 'dp_tkhvmym_lhshq_h_btylnd', 'yy_vts_rylvqyyshn_ltylnd', 'dyvvkh_tm_30_btylnd', 'yy_vts_rylvqyyshn_lvyytnm', 'yy_vts_rylvqyyshn_llvs', 'shyvvq_hkhlqvt_shy_r', 'dp_tylnd', 'dp_tysh', 'dp_lymvdy_shph_tyt', 'dp_md', 'dp_bryt', 'dp_vyytnm', 'dp_ltr', 'dp_myvkhd', 'dp_qvndv', 'lymvdy_shph_vyytnmyt', 'dp_gybvy', 'tlqvmvnyqtsyh', 'dp_tvknyt_khydh_llymvdy_shph', 'dp_nytvkh_mtsbym_bynlvmyym', 'dp_qmbvdyh', 'dp_ltr_thai', 'dp_tvrt_hbvdhvt', 'dp_klklh', 'dp_ysvdvt_hmtmtyqh_vmtmtyqh_ysvd', 'dp_pytvkh_tvknh', 'dp_mshptym' ))
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_term_field_data} "taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_qtgwryh" ON node__field_qtgwryh.field_qtgwryh_target_id = taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_qtgwryh.tid
WHERE ("node_field_data"."status" = '1') AND ((taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_qtgwryh.tid IN('44', '110')))
ORDER BY "node_field_data_created" DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0

My problem is that after this filtering and sorting I still get at least one duplicate of a result for this view. How do I prevent such duplication?

The JOINs are the result of adding the relationship, i.e. you’ve added a relationship to term entities, which requires node -> field table -> term table, so 2 joins. Enabling aggregation and setting the grouping in the filter will probably fix it, but if you’re not using any of the fields from the term entity, do you even need that relationship?
